# how to add facebook pixel to Next.js version 11 website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, facebook-pixel

**I have a problem that if I put my script on Facebook Pixels it does not work and I put it as the following figure, what is the work or what is the problem**

Unfortunately, there are not enough sources to explain this point

here is the _app.js page
// _app.js

```
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../src/theme';
import { projjahNav, projjahNavahFooter } from '../components/index.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { StoreProvider } from '../utils/Store';

export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
      <Script
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
 fbq('init', '5265455546455446'); 
fbq('track', 'PageView');
  `,
  }}
/>
      <noscript>
 <img height="1" width="1" 
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=5265455546455446&ev=PageView
&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
        <title>projja Optics</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <SnackbarProvider
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
        >
          <StoreProvider>
            <projjahahNav />
            {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
            <CssBaseline />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            <projjahahFooter />
          </StoreProvider>
        </SnackbarProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

*I searched, but I can't fully understand it, so what's the problem?*

Comment: The [`next/script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) component should not be used inside `next/head`. It will automatically be added to `<head>`. Check the official example for implementation details: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-facebook-pixel.

Comment: Could you explain more please?

Comment: Move the `Script` component out of the `Head` component's children.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been resolved and all thanks to your help